# Populate 2 Grids with the same Store

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have 2 grids and both of these grids will populate it self from the same store `Person`.

The problem i have is, In the first grid i will load all the Sports and the number of players it has. In the 2nd grid, i will show only the number of medals and gold medals won by a Sport, where `SportID = 3`. How can i do this ? When i load the grid, it gets populated with all

```
 {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    title: 'ALl Sports',
                    store: 'Person',
                    columns: [
                    {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'SportID',
                            text: 'Sport ID'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'SportName',
                            text: 'Sport Name'
                        },                        
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'NoOfPlayers',
                            text: 'No Of Players'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    title: 'Sport Medals for Sport ID 3',
                    store: 'Person',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'noOfMedals',
                            text: 'No Of Medals'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'NoOfGold',
                            text: 'No Of Gold'
                        }
                    ],
```

I have 2 grids and both of these grids will populate it self from the same store `Person`. These 2 grids are in a Window. When the window loads, i populate the grid as follows;

**UPDATE 1** #############################3

```
var personStore = Ext.getStore('Person');
var r = personStore.getAt(0);
personStore.on('load', function() {
    r = personStore.getAt(0);
st.filter({
    filterFn: function(rec) {
        return rec.get('PersonId') == r.get('PersonId'); 
    }


});
personStore.load();
```

#######################3

But, both grid populates with the same set of data. What i want is to display all of the sports Information on Grid 1 (`sportID`,`sportName`,`noOfPlayers`), and Display Sport Information (`noOfMedals`,`noOfGolds`) `WHERE sportId='3'`. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - you can't. If you need to present two different grids at the same time with same store you need to clone store and have another copy of it.

If it's not at the same time - you can use filtering and filter one store before grid is shown.

Comment: How, could i display all the content on one grid and display the filtered content on the 2nd grid ?

Comment: Take a look at store method `filter()` - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

Comment: I know how to use `Filter()`, but not clear how to populate 1 grid with all the records and then populate the 2nd grid with filtered records.

Comment: You bind both grids with same store. And then apply filters before showing grids. Grid will reflect data after it is filtered.

Comment: I have updated my code, with a filter. but still it both grids displays the same filtered record. How do i say that the filtered records should only display in the 2nd grid and not in the first ?

Comment: No. If you're showing both grids at the same time (as you do, right?) - there is no way. You need to clone the store and have two copies of the store.

Answer (score 0):

Create extra stores, based on first store, Apply filter only to second store.

```
    DSScheduleDay: {
        source: '{DSSchedule}',
        filters: [function (rec) {

            return (rec.get('type_id') !== 'V');
        }]
    },

    DSScheduleWeek: {
        source: '{DSSchedule}',
        filters: [function (rec) {

            return (rec.get('type_id') === 'V');
        }]
    },
```